# linux perf: how to interpret and find hotspots

Tags: c++, linux, performance, profiling, perf

I tried out linux' [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) utility today and am having trouble in interpreting its results. I'm used to valgrind's callgrind which is of course a totally different approach to the sampling based method of perf.

What I did:

```
perf record -g -p $(pidof someapp)
perf report -g -n
```

Now I see something like this:

```
+     16.92%  kdevelop  libsqlite3.so.0.8.6               [.] 0x3fe57                                                                                                              ↑
+     10.61%  kdevelop  libQtGui.so.4.7.3                 [.] 0x81e344                                                                                                             ▮
+      7.09%  kdevelop  libc-2.14.so                      [.] 0x85804                                                                                                              ▒
+      4.96%  kdevelop  libQtGui.so.4.7.3                 [.] 0x265b69                                                                                                             ▒
+      3.50%  kdevelop  libQtCore.so.4.7.3                [.] 0x18608d                                                                                                             ▒
+      2.68%  kdevelop  libc-2.14.so                      [.] memcpy                                                                                                               ▒
+      1.15%  kdevelop  [kernel.kallsyms]                 [k] copy_user_generic_string                                                                                             ▒
+      0.90%  kdevelop  libQtGui.so.4.7.3                 [.] QTransform::translate(double, double)                                                                                ▒
+      0.88%  kdevelop  libc-2.14.so                      [.] __libc_malloc                                                                                                        ▒
+      0.85%  kdevelop  libc-2.14.so                      [.] memcpy 
...
```

Ok, these functions might be slow, but how do I find out where they are getting called from? As all these hotspots lie in external libraries I see no way to optimize my code.

Basically I am looking for some kind of callgraph annotated with accumulated cost, where my functions have a higher inclusive sampling cost than the library functions I call.

Is this possible with perf? If so - how?

Note: I found out that "E" unwraps the callgraph and gives somewhat more information. But the callgraph is often not deep enough and/or terminates randomly without giving information about how much info was spent where. Example:

```
-     10.26%  kate  libkatepartinterfaces.so.4.6.0  [.] Kate::TextLoader::readLine(int&...
     Kate::TextLoader::readLine(int&, int&)                                            
     Kate::TextBuffer::load(QString const&, bool&, bool&)                              
     KateBuffer::openFile(QString const&)                                              
     KateDocument::openFile()                                                          
     0x7fe37a81121c
```

Could it be an issue that I'm running on 64 bit? See also: http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2010-November/144952.html (I'm not using fedora but seems to apply to all 64bit systems).

Comment: What version of `perf` are you using?

Comment: I use perf from archlinux' AUR, right now it's at v3.0.3

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should give hotspot a try:
https://www.kdab.com/hotspot-gui-linux-perf-profiler/

It's available on github: https://github.com/KDAB/hotspot

It is for example able to generate flamegraphs for you.

[image: flamegraph]

Comment: yes indeed. Note that I'm the main author of hotspot :) I scratched my own itch!

Comment: There is also the eclipse linux-tools integration available at http://www.eclipse.org/linuxtools/projectPages/perf/

Comment: @milianw - If the application is big data machine learning, then how does `hotspot` and `perf record` help? I observe that most of the profiling details logged are related to libraries, which are required and without that the application can't run. Any pointers on what and how I should interpret the `perf record` data with `hotspot` for big data applications?

Comment: What does this "flamegraph" tell me? Does the x-axis represent time? What does the y-axis represent?

Comment: @FrankPuck http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html

Answer (score 53):

With Linux 3.7 perf is finally able to use DWARF information to generate the callgraph:

```
perf record --call-graph dwarf -- yourapp
perf report -g graph --no-children
```

Neat, but the curses GUI is horrible compared to VTune, KCacheGrind or similar... I recommend to try out FlameGraphs instead, which is a pretty neat visualization: http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html

Note: In the report step, `-g graph` makes the results output simple to understand "relative to total" percentages, rather than "relative to parent" numbers. `--no-children` will show only self cost, rather than inclusive cost - a feature that I also find invaluable.

If you have a new perf and Intel CPU, also try out the LBR unwinder, which has much better performance and produces far smaller result files:

```
perf record --call-graph lbr -- yourapp
```

The downside here is that the call stack depth is more limited compared to the default DWARF unwinder configuration.

Comment: There is http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot capable of converting perf output to dot graphs

Comment: Great news! I haven't been able to get something useful out of this, though. With a debian 2.8 kernel, you first have to recompile the 'perf' tool from the kernel tree with libunwind installed to get this option. I guess for most people, just recompiling stuff with -fno-omit-frame-pointer is easier.

Comment: This doesn't work (any more), another option (--call-graph) has to be provided:
     `perf record -g --call-graph dwarf -- yourapp`
or it will just quit without actually recording any data

Comment: You can use [FlameGraph](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html) for a nice vizualisation of what's hapenning when sampling call stacks.

Answer (score 23):

> Ok, these functions might be slow, but how do I find out where they are getting called from? As all these hotspots lie in external libraries I see no way to optimize my code.

Are you sure that your application `someapp` is built with the gcc option `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` (and possibly its dependant libraries) ? 
Something like this:

```
g++ -m64 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g main.cpp
```

Comment: I presume this answer is just too late to get all the upvotes, because `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` is *the most important* thing to know in profiling.

Answer (score 16):

You can get a very detailed, source level report with `perf annotate`, see [Source level analysis with perf annotate](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Source_level_analysis_with_perf_annotate). It will look something like this (shamelessly stolen from the website):

```
------------------------------------------------
 Percent |   Source code & Disassembly of noploop
------------------------------------------------
         :
         :
         :
         :   Disassembly of section .text:
         :
         :   08048484 <main>:
         :   #include <string.h>
         :   #include <unistd.h>
         :   #include <sys/time.h>
         :
         :   int main(int argc, char **argv)
         :   {
    0.00 :    8048484:       55                      push   %ebp
    0.00 :    8048485:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
[...]
    0.00 :    8048530:       eb 0b                   jmp    804853d <main+0xb9>
         :                           count++;
   14.22 :    8048532:       8b 44 24 2c             mov    0x2c(%esp),%eax
    0.00 :    8048536:       83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
   14.78 :    8048539:       89 44 24 2c             mov    %eax,0x2c(%esp)
         :           memcpy(&tv_end, &tv_now, sizeof(tv_now));
         :           tv_end.tv_sec += strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
         :           while (tv_now.tv_sec < tv_end.tv_sec ||
         :                  tv_now.tv_usec < tv_end.tv_usec) {
         :                   count = 0;
         :                   while (count < 100000000UL)
   14.78 :    804853d:       8b 44 24 2c             mov    0x2c(%esp),%eax
   56.23 :    8048541:       3d ff e0 f5 05          cmp    $0x5f5e0ff,%eax
    0.00 :    8048546:       76 ea                   jbe    8048532 <main+0xae>
[...]
```

Don't forget to pass the `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` and the `-ggdb` flags when you compile your code.

Answer (score 5):

Unless your program has very few functions and hardly ever calls a system function or I/O, profilers that sample the program counter won't tell you much, as you're discovering.
In fact, the well-known profiler *gprof* was created specifically to try to address the uselessness of self-time-only profiling (not that it succeeded).

What actually works is something that samples the *call stack* (thereby finding out where the calls are coming from), on *wall-clock* time (thereby including I/O time), and report *by line or by instruction* (thereby pinpointing the function calls that you should investigate, not just the functions they live in).

Furthermore, the statistic you should look for is *percent of time on stack*, not number of calls, not average inclusive function time. *Especially not "self time".*
If a call instruction (or a non-call instruction) is on the stack 38% of the time, then if you could get rid of it, how much would you save? **38%!**
Pretty simple, no?

An example of such a profiler is [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/).

There are [more issues to be understood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343) on this subject.

Added: @caf got me hunting for the `perf` info, and since you included the command-line argument `-g` it does collect stack samples. Then you can get a [call-tree](http://lwn.net/Articles/340010/) report.
Then if you make sure you're sampling on wall-clock time (so you get wait time as well as cpu time) then you've got *almost* what you need.

Comment: `perf` *does* sample the call stack.  It's just that the report the OP is generating is only showing the leaves.

Comment: @caf: I just [searched again](http://lwn.net/Articles/340010/) and got that if you include the `-g` option it collects stack samples. I assume it can do it on wall-clock time. The OP should find that helpful. Now all that remains is the by-line report.

Comment: @caf: how do I display the whole tree then?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey You can get a very extensive line-by-line report with [`perf annotate`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Source_level_analysis_with_perf_annotate).

Comment: @Ali: I just checked your answer and your link. Does it take stack samples, and for `call` instructions does it record the fraction of samples containing that call somewhere on the stack, and does it sample during voluntary non-process time like file I/O. These things are what are needed, and there is almost no need for measurement precision. I made a (very amateur) [*video on this subject*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPg3sRpdW1U&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I will look into this, please give me some time!

Comment: IMO, high-accuracy / precision profiling with perf counters and so on are useful to help you figure out exactly *why* a CPU-bound hot loop is slow, and how you might speed it up.  Characterizing the overall "where time is spent" view of things is a different problem entirely; there you're looking to maybe redesign things so less work is done, rather than tuning a loop to do the same work faster.  What might be useful for that process is a way to characterize cache footprint spent on copying stuff around, rather than just time, so you could find and change cache-polluting but fast functions.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I've spent so many decades building all kinds of products, and doing performance tuning on all of them. You can't focus on just one kind of performance problem, while saying others are somebody else's problem, especially when nobody knows what they are. But suppose among 10 or so performance problems cascading in size, you do get to a point where some authentic hot-spot is the one you should concentrate on. The samples pin it down it down for you. Then if you think higher precision will tell you how to fix it, be my guest.

Comment: My last comment came out wrong.  I was saying that there *is* a use-case for the high-precision / instruction-level profiling that `perf record` can do; this just isn't it.  That doesn't make it useless or misguided, it just means that feature isn't part of what you need for the kind of profiling that answers *this* question.  Which is a valuable question and one you should ask first, before tuning hot loops.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Forgive me for getting insistent. Comes with the territory :) Stackoverflow is a great resource for programmers because people like you are contributing to it.