# Why do I see __scalbnf in my profiler?

Tags: c++, perf, exp

I am profiling some C++ code with `perf`, and I see that `__scalbnf` and `__wrap_scalbnf` are taking up a good chunk of the run time. I looked up what these functions are, and my best guess is I am calling them via a call to `std::exp`. However I'd like to be able to confirm this. Is there a place where I can see the C++ code implementing std::exp to confirm this? Or what is the best way for me (a C++ amateur) to start digging into this and understanding what is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, if you are using libstdc++ or libc++ you can examine their code.  You might also be able to step into the code with a debugger.

Comment: add a break point to then in a debugger run until it breaks, look at the call stack to find the last known function

Comment: clang libcxx source is here : https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx however it looks like std::exp uses the c functions exp expf expl so reading the c++ code won't help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set a breakpoint on `__scalbn`.  Run your program.  Look at a backtrace (in GDB, `bt`)**.  The call tree will show that `exp()` is a parent function for `__scalbn`.

If a function has multiple callers, the first hit might *not* be from the "hot" function you're profiling.

**To actually figure out which higher-up function (including its children) is responsible for using a lot of time, see [linux perf: how to interpret and find hotspots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031210/linux-perf-how-to-interpret-and-find-hotspots)**.  Top-down profiling can find expensive functions that do all their work in calls to other functions, even when those other functions also have "innocent" callers.  (e.g. `memcpy` is heavily used and often unavoidable, but what you'd want to find are callers that use it too much and could be optimized better.  Or not called at all.)

---

And BTW, yes glibc's math lib `exp()` implementation does internally use `__scalbn`.  I'm not sure how bad the implementation is, but I don't see an asm version for x86-64, only this pure C version.  https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64/s_scalbn.c.html.  (For `__scalbnl(long double)` there's https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/s_scalbnl.S.html, using the x87 `fscale` instruction for 80-bit floats.  But there are only i386 asm files for the other sizes.  And IA-64 (Itanium), but not x86-64).

glibc does have some vectorized EXP code, though, like the SSE4 SVML version https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch/svml_d_exp2_core_sse4.S.html#_ZGVbN2v_exp_sse4.

---

If you want higher-performance `exp()` without perfect accuracy, see [Fastest Implementation of Exponential Function Using AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863719/fastest-implementation-of-exponential-function-using-avx) (that's for `float`, not `double`.  I forget if there's an SO answer with a double version).

Also related: [Efficient implementation of log2(__m256d) in AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770089/efficient-implementation-of-log2-m256d-in-avx2).

Answer (score 1):

To confirm that `std::exp` is the reason for `__scalbnf` and `__wrap_scalbnf`, you can replace the `std::exp` calls by either:

- an identity function that returns the input value
- or by an alternative exp implementation (for example fm_exp, found [here](https://github.com/akohlmey/fastermath))

Then, if you still see `__scalbnf` and `__wrap_scalbnf` in the profiler output, it means it's not coming from std::exp.