# Most relevant performance indicators for C/C++

Tags: performance, optimization, profiling, cpu, benchmarking

I am looking for relevant performance indicators to benchmark and optimize my C/C++ code. For example, virtual memory usage is a simple but efficient indicator, but I know some are more specialized and help in optimizing specific domains : cache hits/misses, context switches, and so on.

*I believe here is a good place to have a list of performance indicators, what they measure, and how to measure them, in order to help people who want to start optimizing their programs know where to start.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **Time is the most relevant indicator.**

This is why most profilers default to measuring / sampling time or core clock cycles.  Understanding where your code spends its time is an essential first step to looking for speedups.  **First find out *what's* slow, then find out *why* it's slow**.

There are 2 fundamentally different kinds of speedups you can look for, and time will help you find both of them.

- **Algorithmic improvements: finding ways to do less work in the first place**.  This is often the most important kind, and the one Mike Dunlavey's answer focuses on.  You should definitely *not* ignore this.  Caching a result that's slow to recompute can be very worth it, especially if it's slow enough that loading from DRAM is still faster.

  Using data structures / algorithms that can more efficiently solve your problem on real CPUs is somewhere between these two kinds of speedups.  (e.g. linked lists are in practice often slower than arrays because pointer-chasing latency is a bottleneck, unless you end up copying large arrays too often...)
- **Applying brute force more efficiently to do the same work in fewer cycles**. (And/or more friendly to the rest of the program with smaller cache footprint and/or less branching that takes up space in the branch predictors, or whatever.)

  Often involves changing your data layout to be more cache friendly, and/or manually vectorizing with SIMD.  Or doing so in a smarter way.  Or writing a function that handles a common special case faster than your general-case function.  Or even hand-holding the compiler into making better asm for your C source.

  Consider summing an array of `float` on modern x86-64: Going from latency-bound scalar addition to AVX SIMD with multiple accumulators can give you a speedup of 8 (elements per vector) * 8 (latency / throughput on Skylake) = 64x for a medium-sized array (still on a single core/thread), in the theoretical best case where you don't run into another bottleneck (like memory bandwidth if your data isn't hot in L1d cache).  Skylake `vaddps` / `vaddss` has 4 cycle latency, and 2-per-clock = 0.5c reciprocal throughput.  (https://agner.org/optimize/).  [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction) for more about multiple accumulators to hide FP latency.  But this still loses hard vs. storing the total somewhere, and maybe even updating the total with a delta when you change an element.  (FP rounding error can accumulate that way, though, unlike integers.)

---

If you don't see an obvious algorithmic improvement, or want to know more before making changes, check whether the CPU is stalling on anything, or if it's efficiency chewing through all the work the compiler is making it do.

**Instructions per clock (IPC)** tells you whether the CPU is close to its max instruction throughput or not.  (Or more accurately, fused-domain uops issued per clock on x86, because for example one `rep movsb` instruction is a whole big memcpy and decodes to many many uops.  And cmp/jcc fuses from 2 instructions to 1 uop, increasing IPC but the pipeline width is still fixed.)

**Work done per instruction is a factor, too, but isn't something you can measure with a profiler**: if you have the expertise, look at compiler-generated asm to see if the same work with fewer instructions is possible.  If the compiler didn't auto-vectorize, or did so inefficiently, you can maybe get a lot more work done per instruction by manually vectorizing with SIMD intrinsics, depending on the problem.  Or by hand-holding the compiler into emitting better asm by tweaking your C source to compute things in a way that is natural for asm.  e.g. [What is the efficient way to count set bits at a position or lower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407437/what-is-the-efficient-way-to-count-set-bits-at-a-position-or-lower/34410357#34410357).  And see also [C++ code for testing the Collatz conjecture faster than hand-written assembly - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/c-code-for-testing-the-collatz-conjecture-faster-than-hand-written-assembly)

---

**If you find low IPC, figure out why** by considering possibilities like cache misses or branch misses, or long dependency chains (often a cause of low IPC when not bottlenecked on the front-end or memory).

Or you might find that it's already close to optimally applying the available brute force of the CPU (unlikely but possible for some problems).  In that case your only hope is algorithmic improvements to do less work.

(CPU frequency isn't fixed, but core clock cycles is a good proxy.  If your program doesn't spend time waiting for I/O, then core clock cycles is maybe *more* useful to measure.)

**A mostly-serial portion of a multi-threaded program can be hard to detect**; most tools don't have an easy way to find threads using cycles when other threads are blocked.

---

Time spent in a function isn't the *only* indicator, though.  **A function can make the rest of the program slow by touching a lot of memory**, resulting in eviction of other useful data from cache.  So that kind of effect is possible.  Or having a lot of branches somewhere can maybe occupy some of the branch-prediction capacity of the CPU, resulting in more branch misses elsewhere.

---

**But note that simply finding where the CPU is spending a lot of time executing is not the most useful,** in a large codebase where functions containing hotspots can have multiple callers.  e.g. lots of time spent in memcpy doesn't mean you need to speed up memcpy, it means you need to find which caller is calling memcpy a lot.  And so on back up the call tree.

**Use profilers that can record stack snapshots**, or just hit control-C in a debugger and look at the call stack a few times.  If a certain function usually appears in the call stack, it's making expensive calls.

Related: [linux perf: how to interpret and find hotspots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031210/linux-perf-how-to-interpret-and-find-hotspots), especially Mike Dunlavey's answer there makes this point.

---

#### Algorithmic improvements to avoid doing work at all are often much more valuable than doing the same work more efficiently.

But if you find very low IPC for some work you haven't figured out how to avoid yet, then sure take a look at rearranging your data structures for better caching, or avoiding branch mispredicts.

Or if high IPC is still taking a long time, manually vectorizing a loop can help, doing 4x or more work per instruction.

Comment: I would love to have the ability to upvote again after this great edit. Thanks a lot for answering with such a thorough, complete, deep explanation

Answer (score 1):

@PeterCordes answers are always good. I can only add my own perspective, coming from about 40 years optimizing code:

If there is time to be saved (which there is), that time is spent doing something unnecessary, that you can get rid of if you know what it is.

So what is it? Since you don't know what it is, you also don't know how much time it takes, *but* it does take time. The more time it takes, the more worthwhile it is to find, and the easier it is to find it. Suppose it takes 30% of the time. That means a random-time snapshot has a 30% chance of showing you what it is.

I take 5-10 random snapshots of the call stack, using a debugger and the "pause" function.

If I see it doing something on more than one snapshot, and that thing can be done faster or not at all, I've got a substantial speedup, guaranteed.
Then the process can be repeated to find more speedups, until I hit diminishing returns.

The important thing about this method is - *no "bottleneck" can hide from it*. That sets it apart from profilers which, because they summarize, speedups can hide from them.

Comment: All right, I've got it. From here, I need to move on from 'I know where the bottleneck is' to 'I know what the bottleneck is'. Any clue on how to keep progressing ? My code 'looks' optimized but obviously isn't...

Comment: @Magix: Oh, I've been a pest on this subject, with many (controversial) posts on stackoverflow. And I made a [*video of it*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPg3sRpdW1U&t=1s) a few years back. Maybe that will get the point across. It's only about 8 minutes. If I can help any more, let me know.

Comment: Great, can you point me to links that explain what a 'frontend', 'backend', 'dependency chain' and all the other cpu design words means ?